# How to do sorting by date in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have to sort the values by date column. I am using jQuery Datatable, here sorting is not working by date filed.

```
var settings = {
    ajax: {
        url: url.toString(),
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend:function() {
            showSpinner(".spinnerDiv", true);
        },
        complete:function() {
            showSpinner(".spinnerDiv", false);
        },
        data: function ( d ) {
            d.selectedButtonName = $("#selected_button_name").val();
            d.salesDaysToDisplay = $("#salesDaysToDisplay").val();
            d.selectedContributorUserId = $("#selected_contributor_userid").val();
        }
    },
    order: [[12,"desc"]],
    pageLength: 100,
    columns : [
        { data: "cashOutId" },
        { data: "thumbnail" },
        { data: "thumbnail" },
        { data: "invoiceNo" },
        { data: "saleDate" },
        { data: "salePaymentStatus" },
        { data: "docId" },
        { data: "description" },
        { data: "customerName" },
        { data: "intlPaymentAmount" },
        { data: "exchangeRate" },
        { data: "totalAmount" }

    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                var result = "";
                var cashOutAmount = row.cashOutAmount.replace("$", "").replace(",", "");
                var disableCashOut = (Math.sign(cashOutAmount) == -1) ? "disabled='disabled' checked" : "";
                if (row.paymentStatus == 'Unpaid' && row.saleDate && !row.isRedOrBlue) {
                    result = "<input type='checkbox' class='cashOutCb' "+disableCashOut+" value='" + data + "' data-cashoutamount='" + cashOutAmount + "'/>";
                }

                return result;
            },
            "targets": [0]
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return "<image class='tinyThumb' src='" + data + "'/>";
            },
            "targets": [1]
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return "<a href='" + data + "'>"+data+"</a>";
            },
            "targets": [2]
        },
        {
            "sType": "royaltiesTrxDateTime",
            "targets" : [4]
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var shortDescription = data, len = data.length, result = "", rowIndex = "fullDescription"+meta.row;

                if (len > 75) {
                    shortDescription = shortDescription.substring(0, 75);
                    result = '<div><span id="'+rowIndex+'" style="display:none;">'+data+' <a class="showLess" href="javascript:void(0);">less</a></span><span class="shortDescription">'+shortDescription+' ...  <a data-id='+meta.row+' href="javascript:void(0);" class="showMore">more</a></span></div>';
                } else {
                    result = "<div>"+shortDescription+"</div>";
                }
                return result;
            },
            "targets": [7]
        },
        { "class": "dtRightAlign", "targets": [11, 13, 14, 15] },
        { "class": "hideInDatatable", "targets": [2, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26] },
        { targets: '_all', sortable: true, searchable: true }
    ],
    "footerCallback": function () {
        var api = this.api(), columns = [11, 13, 15];
        var colspanA = [9, 1, 1], colspanB = [1, 1, 2];
        $('tfoot tr').html("");
        var fclass = "dtRightAlign";
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            var pageTotal = api.column(columns[i], {filter: 'applied', page: 'current'}).data().sum();
            var total = api.column(columns[i], { filter: 'applied' }).data().sum();
            if (pageTotal != 0 || total != 0)
                $('tfoot tr').append('<td colspan="'+colspanA[i]+'" class="'+fclass+'"> $' + parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) + '</td><td colspan="'+colspanB[i]+'"></td>');
        }
    },
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath":'<%=request.getContextPath()+"/js/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"%>',
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sFileName" : "Contributor Report-"+timeStamp+".csv",
                "sTitle" : "Contributor Report",
                "mColumns": [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26],
                "sButtonText": "Create Excel Report",
                "aButtons":["xls"]
            }
        ],
    }
};

dataTable = $('#purchase-table').DataTable(settings);
```

For date sorting I am using the below method.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["royaltiesTrxDateTime-desc"] = function (x, y) {
    var dateStr1 = x, dateStr2 = y;
    var d1 = moment(dateStr1.trim(), 'D-MMM-YYYY HH:mm', true).format();
    var d2 = moment(dateStr2.trim(), 'D-MMM-YYYY HH:mm', true).format();
    return moment(d1).isAfter(moment(d2)) ? -1 : 1;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["royaltiesTrxDateTime-asc"] = function (x, y) {
    return jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["royaltiesTrxDateTime-desc"](y, x);
}
```

The above jQuery function is working fine in other place, here it is not working properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your dates look like? What format?

Comment: d/m/y format. but i added the jquery function and below code to json {
                    "sType": "royaltiesTrxDateTime", 
                    "targets" : [4] 
                   },

Comment: @david : Now i did some changes in my code, when i click the dates column it is calling the desc function always and i am getting the values of dateStr1 and dateStr2 like (17-Jan-2017). but it is not chaing the order.

Comment: Fakkir, I still dont get why you are doing this. How is the format of your dates? You only need momentjs if you have dates that is not natively parseable, or if you want to show a date in a certain fashion.